# Django IntegrityError: no default value

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

There is a longer SQL query that I need to run to migrate data from one table to another. It worked fine all the way up to this week when I migrated to Django 1.9.2 and Python 3.5.

The problem is that the table has a field 'last_update' that is NULL by default. The table definition is

```
last_update = models.DateTimeField("last updated",null=True, auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
```

I've also checked with MySQL Workbench and the table is indeed set to allow NULLs on that field and the default is NULL.

The query crashes after about 30 minutes with the error message:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'last_update' doesn't have a default value")
```

Very irritating! How can I insert rows to that table?

Per request, here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `google_pla_plaproducts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_code` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `min_bid` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  `current_bid` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  `max_bid` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime(6),
  `last_update` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_change` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starting_bid` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  `adgroup_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_price` decimal(20,4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`product_code`,`adgroup_id`),
  KEY `google_p_adgroup_id_3b7c9d4ecddd04ba_fk_google_pla_plaadgroup_id` (`adgroup_id`),
  KEY `google_pla_plaprod_status_id_2f8113a5ef0dd021_fk_globs_status_id` (`status_id`),
  KEY `idx_prod_code` (`product_code`),
  CONSTRAINT `google_p_adgroup_id_3b7c9d4ecddd04ba_fk_google_pla_plaadgroup_id` FOREIGN KEY (`adgroup_id`) REFERENCES `google_pla_plaadgroup` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `google_pla_plaprod_status_id_2f8113a5ef0dd021_fk_globs_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `globs_status` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=88949 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Comment: Can you add the SQL definition of the table that workbench produces?

Comment: Also worth noting that the table actually contains null values for that field!

Comment: Maybe add `models.DateTimeField(default=None, ...)`

Comment: try delete your django migrations files in that app then use python manage.py makemigrations-> migrate again.

Comment: @Aison I did play around with the migrations for a while. Eventually is just started to work.

Answer (score 0):

`updated = models.DateTimeField(default=None, auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)`

this should work.
i have used this before and it is working fine for me.

Comment: You don't need `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField): "The options auto_now_add, auto_now, and default are mutually exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error."

Comment: @Rohit Chopra: No, that wasn't it. It somehow worked again. Maybe after playing around with the migrations files...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the table a few times. I didn't try the suggestion from Rohit, as the default=None. It started working again, after using multiple DB migrations.